# Cache not created on Geoserver with data from Postgres

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, file-geodatabase, geowebcache

I have the following setup,
Geoserver instance running on Azure (PaaS)
Postgres instance running on Azure (PaaS) with Postgis

I have a 20 gb .fgdb(Esri file geodatabase) format data, which i imported into postgres.
I added the postgres as a store in the Geoserver and published the same layer. When i use the geowebcache page to create cache(seed), the task to create cache is created but no tiles are generated and no files are generated in the cache folder.

Following the log file

```
2017-06-20 06:04:48,833 INFO [seed.SeedTask] - GWC Seeder Thread-2 begins seeding layer : GEOSR:ofz
2017-06-20 06:04:48,834 INFO [seed.SeedTask] - GWC Seeder Thread-3 begins seeding layer : GEOSR:ofz
2017-06-20 06:04:48,836 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2017-06-20 06:04:48,836 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2017-06-20 06:05:48,988 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: This request used more time than allowed and has been forcefully stopped. Max rendering time is 60.0s
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:573)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:273)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:143)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.executeInternal(GetMap.java:623)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:279)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:125)
    at org.geoserver.wms.DefaultWebMapService.getMap(DefaultWebMapService.java:320)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.geoserver.kml.WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.invoke(WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:62)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:36)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:80)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.getMap(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:857)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:268)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:147)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.GWC.dispatchOwsRequest(GWC.java:1272)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.dispatchGetMap(GeoServerTileLayer.java:661)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getMetatilingReponse(GeoServerTileLayer.java:605)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.seedTile(GeoServerTileLayer.java:800)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.SeedTask.doActionInternal(SeedTask.java:136)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.GWCTask.doAction(GWCTask.java:76)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:36)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:25)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2017-06-20 06:05:48,989 ERROR [seed.MTSeeder] - Problem communicating with GeoServer
org.geowebcache.GeoWebCacheException: Problem communicating with GeoServer
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getMetatilingReponse(GeoServerTileLayer.java:611)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.seedTile(GeoServerTileLayer.java:800)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.SeedTask.doActionInternal(SeedTask.java:136)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.GWCTask.doAction(GWCTask.java:76)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:36)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:25)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected: RenderedImageMap, got null
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.dispatchGetMap(GeoServerTileLayer.java:664)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getMetatilingReponse(GeoServerTileLayer.java:605)
    ... 9 more
2017-06-20 06:05:48,990 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: This request used more time than allowed and has been forcefully stopped. Max rendering time is 60.0s
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:573)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:273)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:143)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.executeInternal(GetMap.java:623)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:279)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:125)
    at org.geoserver.wms.DefaultWebMapService.getMap(DefaultWebMapService.java:320)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.geoserver.kml.WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.invoke(WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:62)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:36)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:80)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.getMap(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:857)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:268)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:147)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.GWC.dispatchOwsRequest(GWC.java:1272)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.dispatchGetMap(GeoServerTileLayer.java:661)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getMetatilingReponse(GeoServerTileLayer.java:605)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.seedTile(GeoServerTileLayer.java:800)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.SeedTask.doActionInternal(SeedTask.java:136)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.GWCTask.doAction(GWCTask.java:76)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:36)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:25)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2017-06-20 06:05:49,071 INFO [seed.GWCTask] - Thread group finished RESEED task after 60.238 seconds
2017-06-20 06:05:49,072 ERROR [seed.MTSeeder] - Problem communicating with GeoServer
org.geowebcache.GeoWebCacheException: Problem communicating with GeoServer
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getMetatilingReponse(GeoServerTileLayer.java:611)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.seedTile(GeoServerTileLayer.java:800)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.SeedTask.doActionInternal(SeedTask.java:136)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.GWCTask.doAction(GWCTask.java:76)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:36)
    at org.geowebcache.seed.MTSeeder.call(MTSeeder.java:25)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected: RenderedImageMap, got null
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.dispatchGetMap(GeoServerTileLayer.java:664)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getMetatilingReponse(GeoServerTileLayer.java:605)
    ... 9 more
```

Infact the above issue happened even when i had the same setup on a single machine. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Following is the log file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know these GeoServer errors look incomprehensible, and that is very long, but here's the salient part:

> ServiceException: This request used more time than allowed and has been forcefully stopped. Max rendering time is 60.0s

This means that rendering one of your tiles is taking more than 60 s, which is a really long time.

Can you preview the layer? (Do this through the GeoServer UI, if you want. Potentially turn on 'tiling' to see it tiled.)

If your preview is failing too, you've definitely got issues, either with your style, or with the data size. Probably the style.

You can check whether it's the style by using a very simple style, like the default polygon. If that is still failing, you may need to change the data, perhaps by adding a spatial index.

If you need to add a spatial index, look at the data import process, as there may be a flag to create the index.

Comment: also you can increase the time out in the WMS page of the UI

Comment: For now i increased the timeout for rendering to a larger time period. Now the tiles are getting generated and works pretty well.

Comment: @AlexLeith thanks that worked well for me. Can you also suggest links that talks about performance of geoserver and indexing on posgres. Thanks

Comment: Hi @ShreyesShiv, if you can connect to Postgres, do check whether you have an index, as if you don't have a spatial index, it'll slow it down a lot (like, 100x!). Here's some reading: http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/indexing.html - A spatial index in Postgres is easy, and not very fancy. If you need to go further in optimising, something to think about is using a simplified geometry when zoomed out and only showing detail when zoomed in. Here's more reading: http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/enterprise/vector.html